# API to get list of movies by actor or director?

Tags: web-services, api

I am looking for an api to download a list of movies when the search term is an actor, actress or director.

So if actor = "Tom Cruise", I get a list of all his movies.
If director = "James Cameron", I get a list of all the movies he directed.

I have checked the sites which use iMDB's api but they search by movie title or imdb id.
Same for [RottenTomatoes](http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs).

I am aware of [IMDb's text files](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.theimdbapi.org makes this information available via a RESTful JSON API.

From their examples:

```
http://www.theimdbapi.org/api/find/person?name=jim+carrey
```

returns all of the info regarding Jim Carrey's films.

I don't believe that it has the parameters to get quite as detailed as you were hoping for, but it could certainly give you the bulk of the information you need.

Edit:

I also noticed that the other posted solution is no longer working. Seems that the location of the documentation for themoviedb.org is actually at this location now:

https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/people

Honestly, it seems a bit more robust.

(I also realized after posting how old this actual issue is, but hopefully it is still helpful to someone who stumbles upon it.. )